# Java - File Management

Tags: java, client-server, attachment

## Hello Folks!

### It's rather a *generally* than a *technical* question.

It's about how to (*cleverly*) manage Files within a Java *Server* / *Client* Application.

#### My Idea is as follows ...

I want users to be able to add Attachments to a dataset.

## As it is ...

At this moment I have implemented this funcionallity within a ***MySQL*** Database and ***Blobbing***. As you can figure out, this isn't really clever... but I just wanted to get this thing working.

Now my Database weighs about **4** to **5 GiBs**. - Well now I gotta improve this thing.

## My new Concept ...

Now I thought it would be clever to generally recode my database access from direct *jdbc* accessing to *WebServices* to improve the *usability* and *accessibility*. Side effect of that would be the possibility to easily outsource file management to the server's filesystem.

Well ... as far as this I got it myself. But now my 'problem' is... How should I store my Files?

#### I got...

- Different **Users**
- Different **Domains**
- Different **Access Roles**
- Different **Dataset Types**

Nearly each type of dataset can contain an attachment and every user can access those attachments.

Is it clever to create a subdir for every user and store his attachments in that dir? - Because I heard Java would get very slow if there are too many files in a dir...
Should I create a **APPDIR** \ **USERDIR** \ **YEAR_MONTH** \ **FILENAME.txt** hierarchy on the server?

Or does someone know a completly different but pretty much better solution for that?

Googling for a *Java File Management Frameworks* didn't really help me ... So I thought at least one of the [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) users would have a great idea for that!

#### Thanks in advance!

Comment: Geez, how did you manage to format your post like that....

Comment: Generally question are better posted on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kayaman - Hard work, it was my padavan ;)

Comment: @Holger - Thank's... Didn't know that but now I know for next time...